# Load filenames without extension to CheckedListBox

Tags: c#, filenames, openfiledialog, checkedlistbox, folderbrowserdialog

I have a checkedListBox; wich loads **files** inside a folder; to run/open when checked.

What I'm trying to achieve is to: 
 
- Load filenames without extension into the CheckedListBox.

**I can retrieve:**

```
"C:\Folder1\anotherfolder\myfile1.txt"
```

but; i just want to be retrieve: the "filename" (with or without the extention).

**Something Like:**

```
"myfile1.txt"
```

I was attempting to do this with folderBrowserDialog, but I have no idea on how to accomplish this.

**My Current Code:**

```
//...
    private string openFileName, folderName;
    private bool fileOpened = false;
//...

        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();

        if (!fileOpened)
        {
            ofd.InitialDirectory = fbd.SelectedPath;
            ofd.FileName = null;


            fbd.Description = "Please select your *.txt folder";
            fbd.RootFolder = System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer;
            if (fbd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string foldername = fbd.SelectedPath;
                foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(foldername))
                checkedListBox1.Items.Add(f);
            }
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need an OpenFileDialog at all, simply change the line that adds the files to

```
checkedListBox1.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(f));
```

Just remember to add

```
using System.IO;
```

And you can also reduce everything to one line code

```
checkedListBox1.Items.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(fbd.SelectedPath).Select(x => Path.GetFileName(x)).ToArray());
```

Comment: Glad to be of help, to deepen your understanding search for "Lambda Expressions" and IEnumerable<T> extension methods